# Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:extractDebugAnnotations'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

facing this error during runtime in flutter. App is connected to firebase successfully. also taking too much time in running i am using android studio.

//dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

---

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cloud_firestore:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':cloud_firestore:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.5.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.5.0/kotlin-compiler-26.5.0.jar'.
         > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 24538383; received: 14942096

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 20s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you find the solution for this problem? Please suggest, I am facing the same..

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

1. Upgrading Gradle to version 5.4.1 .
2. Upgrading Gradle plugin version to 3.5.0 .
3. Run the command `./gradlew dependencies` in project's android directory which downloaded missing path_provider dependencies.
4. Run `flutter clean` then `flutter run`.